# Trying to route Heroku to index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I am using Heroku to deploy my website, and am using node.js. In my index.js file, the tutorial uses "Hello World" in the response.end; however I want it to display my index.html file instead. How would I do this?

```js
var http = require('http')

http.createServer(function (request, response){
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"})
    response.end("Hello World/n")
}).listen(process.env.PORT)
```

Comment: change `response.end("hello world") to response.sendFile('index.html')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:
`fs.readFile` reads your html file and converts it to buffer.
`response.writeHead` defines the response header and specifies the content type as html.
`response.end` sends the file and completes the response.

```
var http = require('http')
var fs = require('fs')

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  fs.readFile('index.html', function (err, file) {
    response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" })
    response.end(file)
  })
})
  .listen(process.env.PORT)
```